# How to fix Pyinstaller making an executable that doesn't run

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I'm running python 3.7.0 32 bit version. I'm having issues turning a script into an executable. Pyinstaller successfully creates the build and dist folders and I have an executable but it doesn't do anything when I run it.

I've read other issues and I've used set Path=%Path%;C:\Windows\System32\downlevel; and i don't receive any warning about my dll files so they're all good. I have also tried on python 3.6.2 and experienced the same issues, I'm not sure whats going on.

This is the Hello World program I tried to do:

```
import tkinter as tk
class Go:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.master = root
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.testLabel = tk.Label(self.frame,text='hello world')
        self.testLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.frame.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x600')
    app = Go(root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Run of pyinstaller:

```
C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>set Path=%Path%;C:\Windows\System32\downlevel;

C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\Scripts>pyinstaller --onefile test.py
73 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
75 INFO: Python: 3.7.0
76 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
77 INFO: wrote C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\Scripts\test.spec
83 INFO: UPX is not available.
87 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\kiern\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37- 
32\\Scripts',
'C:\\Users\\kiern\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37- 
32\\Scripts']
87 INFO: checking Analysis
91 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
91 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
96 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
100 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4348 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4381 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
required by c:\users\kiern\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
4792 INFO: Caching module hooks...
4798 INFO: Analyzing 
C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\test.py
4978 INFO: Loading module hooks...
4979 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
5081 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
5084 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
5360 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
5624 INFO: checking Tree
5627 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
5629 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
5751 INFO: checking Tree
5754 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
5755 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
5798 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
5798 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
5803 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
5814 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
6094 INFO: Looking for eggs
6095 INFO: Using Python library 
c:\users\kiern\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
6096 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
6163 INFO: Warnings written to 
C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\Scripts\build\test\warn-test.txt
6264 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to 
C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\Scripts\build\test\xref-test.html
6323 INFO: checking PYZ
6323 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
6324 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\Scripts\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz
6937 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\Scripts\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
6947 INFO: checking PKG
6947 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
6951 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
9744 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
9812 INFO: Bootloader 
c:\users\kiern\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
9812 INFO: checking EXE
9817 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
9820 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
9822 INFO: Appending archive to EXE 
C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\Scripts\dist\test.exe
9832 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

C:\Users\kiern\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>
```

My expected goal is to have an executable that actually shows something. Any help please?

Edit:
I just tried to do a simple program that does the main then prints hello world and the same issue occurred, the executable brings the cmd up for like 1 second then crashes or just stops and nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and runs without any errors but there is no output to see because you are forgetting to add `mainloop()` function to show your TK window.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Go:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.testLabel = tk.Label(self.frame, text='hello world')
        self.testLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.frame.pack()
        # dont forget this
        self.master.mainloop()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x600')
    Go(root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then you can simply freeze your app with `pyinstaller -F script.py`.

Comment: Oh my god, you don’t know how long I spent messing around with my Pyinstaller setting, setting the path and system variables for tk and tcl. Thank you so much!!!! I really appreciate it!